# Bind ListView with Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind ListView with TestRow class as below

```
  <Grid Background="White">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BindingTest}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="176" Margin="49,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>


  public ObservableCollection<TestRow> BindingTest
         => ListToObservableCollection<TestRow>.ObservableCollectionFromList(new List<TestRow>
         {
                new TestRow(1, "jack"),
                new TestRow(2, "mark")
         });
```

After start ListView shows "XXXX.TestoRow" twice. However when I am binding `List<int>` it is working corret.
How then I can bind my own objects to ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DisplayMemberPath. If TestRow has fields:

```
class TestRow
{
  public int Index {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

then use

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BindingTest}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="176" Margin="49,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197">
```

and selected values would be TestRow.